# Run lm with multiple responses and weights

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I have to fit a linear model with the same model matrix to multiple responses. This can be easily done in R by specifying the response as matrix instead of a vector. Computation is very fast in this way.

Now I would also like to add weights to the model that correspond to the accuracy of responses. Therefore, for each response vector I would need also different weight vector. However, `lm` allows to enter the weights only as a vector not matrix. So I could not enter the weights in batch and would have to run `lm` for every response separately. This way the calculations would become much slower.

Is there any way run these type of models in batch mode, without calling `lm` repeatedly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Because this question is just about R, it would be better on StackOverflow. I've marked it for migration there.

Comment: have you looked at using `lm.fit` ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. In the the code of `lm.wfit` you see `z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x * wts, y * wts, tol)`. That means `x` and `y` are both transformed using the same weights. That`s not possible, if you want different weights for your multiple responses.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I would also like to add weights to the model that correspond to the accuracy of responses. Therefore, for each response vector I would need also different weight vector. However, the `lm` allows to enter the weights only as a vector not matrix. So I could not enter the weights in batch and would have to run `lm` for every response separately. This way the calculations would become much slower.

As explained in [Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262534/4891738), efficiency of "mlm" demands a shared model matrix for all LHS responses. However, weighted regression gives no reuse of model matrix, as for a different set of weights, both response `y` and model matrix `X` need be rescaled. Have a read on [R: lm() result differs when using `weights` argument and when using manually reweighted data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39315867/4891738) to see how weighted regression works.

> Is there any way run these type of models in batch mode, without calling `lm` repeatedly?

It depends on what you want. If you need a full `lmObject`, then you have to call `lm` every time. If you only want coefficients, you may use `.lm.fit`. The 2nd link above has demonstrated the use of `lm.fit`, while the use of `.lm.fit` is almost identical. A simple template may be the following:

```
## weighted mlm, by specifying matrix directly
## `xmat`: non-weighted model matrix, manually created from `model.matrix`
## `ymat`: non-weighted response matrix
## `wmat`: matrix of weights

## all matrices must have the same number of rows (not checked)
## `ymat` and `wmat` must have the same number of columns (not checked)
## no `NA` values in any where is allowed (not checked)
## all elements of `wmat` must be strictly positive (not checked)

wmlm <- function (xmat, ymat, wmat) {
  N <- ncol(ymat)
  wmlmList <- vector("list", length = N)
  for (j in 1:N) {
    rw <- sqrt(wmat[, j])
    wmlmList[[j]] <- .lm.fit(rw * xmat, rw * ymat[, j])
    }
  return(wmlmList)
  }
```

Consider a simple example of its use:

```
## a toy dataset of 200 data with 3 numerical variables and 1 factor variable
dat <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(200), x2 = rnorm(200), x3 = rnorm(200), f = gl(5, 40, labels = letters[1:5]))

## consider a model `~ x1 + poly(x3, 3) + x2 * f`
## we construct the non-weighted model matrix
xmat <- model.matrix (~ x1 + poly(x3, 3) + x2 * f, dat)

## now let's assume we have 100 model responses as well as 100 sets of weights
ymat <- matrix(rnorm(200 * 100), 200)
wmat <- matrix(runif(200 * 100), 200)

## Let's call `wmlm`:
fit <- wmlm (xmat, ymat, wmat)
```

`.lm.fit` returns critical information for further model inference, and a complete `lmObject` would inherit most of these entries.

```
## take the first fitted model as an example
str(fit[[1]])
 #$ qr          : num [1:200, 1:14] -10.4116 0.061 0.0828 0.0757 0.0698 ...
 # ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:14] 0 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 ...
 # ..- attr(*, "contrasts")=List of 1
 # .. ..$ f: chr "contr.treatment"
 # ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 # .. ..$ : chr [1:200] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 # .. ..$ : chr [1:14] "(Intercept)" "x1" "poly(x3, 3)1" "poly(x3, 3)2" ...
 #$ coefficients: num [1:14] 0.1184 -0.0506 0.3032 0.1643 0.4269 ...
 #$ residuals   : num [1:200] -0.7311 -0.0795 -0.2495 0.4097 0.0495 ...
 #$ effects     : num [1:200] -0.351 -0.36 0.145 0.182 0.291 ...
 #$ rank        : int 14
 #$ pivot       : int [1:14] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 #$ qraux       : num [1:14] 1.06 1.13 1.07 1.05 1.01 ...
 #$ tol         : num 1e-07
 #$ pivoted     : logi FALSE
```

Result of `.lm.fit` has no supported generic functions like `summary`, `anova`, `predict`, `plot`, etc. But inference of a linear model is easy, so it is straightforward to compute yourself (provided you know the theory behind):

1. t-statistic table for regression coefficients (from `$qr`);
2. F-statistic and ANOVA table (from `$effects`);
3. residual standard error, R-squared and adjusted R-squared (from `$residulas` and `$rank`).

---

Finally, I offer a benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(wmlm = {wmlm (xmat, ymat, wmat);},
               lm = {for (i in 1:ncol(ymat))
                       lm(ymat[, i] ~ x1 + poly(x3, 3) + x2 * f, dat, weights = wmat[, i]);} )

#Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
# wmlm  20.84512  23.02756  27.29539  24.49314  25.9027  79.8894   100  a 
#   lm 400.53000 405.10622 430.09787 414.42152 442.2640 535.9144   100   b
```

So 17.25 times boost is seen (based on median time).